# Inserting a line break in Arabic and Urdu text

Tags: c#, arabic, arabic-support

I'm trying to insert a line break in between Arabic/Urdu text where there is a number in between.

```
  outPut.Insert(index,  " " + (char)0x202B + " " + (char)0x000A + (char)0x000D +  " " + (char)0x202C+ (char)0x200F+ " ");
```

Please help, it doesn't work! It doesn't give a line break:

```
ئي۔ .13 اَلَّذِ
```

Comment: Welcome to SO John! What _exactly_ doesn't work? Can you show us what your output is and what you would like it to be?

Comment: Don't know if it is the cause for your problem, but LF+CR is not the line break sequence as used by Windows, so depending on how you process your strings, this may or may not cause a problem...

Comment: @AlG Thank you, I've added sample output. Please advise!

Comment: @elgonzo Thank you, I've added sample output. So on windows, could you please let me know how this should be handled. Even opening in a text processor and applying a line - break doesn't work.

Comment: What is your `output`? I tried `Debug.Print("123 " + (char)0x202B + " " + (char)0x000A + (char)0x000D + " " + (char)0x202C + (char)0x200F + " 456");` gives 2 line breaks in output console, although the Arabic text is not shown (it may because my environment). Have you tried `Environment.NewLine`? Have you tried non Arabic text? PS, if `output` is a `TextBox`, have you turned on `MultiLine` property?